# iOS 7/8 system keyboard height

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, keyboard

I've spent a few days trying to research this as I feel the answer would be a 1 liner, but here goes:

This question does not refer to custom keyboards on iOS but to the system keyboard that pops up for first responders.

I noticed that the default keyboard on most apps is shorter and more slick than the keyboard I end up getting on my app.
Here are the keyboards (sorry for not uploading the photos, I don't have enough rep yet)

Most apps:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4iIa.png

The keyboard I'm getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlqzT.png

Is it a some config that I'm missing? An OS version target issue?

Thanks!

Comment: i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your code:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Where `textField` is your text field or text view that is showing the keyboard.

Comment: Hi, I'm not referring to the auto correction type. Note that the keyboard itself is taller, there's more padding between each row.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a custom keyboard enabled on your device - you can disable it within the keyboard settings at the OS level. The "stretched" keyboard some apps experience is related to the scaling that takes place to stretch up iOS 7 apps to iPhone 6/6+ but it doesn't look like this is the issue you're experiencing based on the screenshots.